# Whats the Definition of different layouts in webpage that is Two Column,Three Column ,Multi Col,Border Layout and Two Panel Layout?

Tags: website-design, page-layout

Definitions needed for Two Column,Three Column ,Multi Column,Border Layout and Two Panel Layout which will be helpful in documenting Technical Design document

Comment: "Two column layout", "Three column layout", "Multi column layout", "Border layout" and "Two panel layout". There isn't anything more fancy to describe them. Don't complicate something that describes exactly what it refers to.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey You should put that as an answer to the question intead of a comment. I guess you're an information Architect who have done a lot of work with labeling ;-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg - I feel bad posting such a thing as a full blown answer. I'll try to beef it up some. :)

Answer (score 2):

User Experience shares a principle with many other practices that tells us to not overcomplicate things. The [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_it_simple_stupid).

From Wikipedia:

> KISS is an acronym for "Keep it simple, stupid" as a design principle noted by the U.S. Navy in 1960. The KISS principle states that most systems work best if they are kept simple rather than made complicated; therefore simplicity should be a key goal in design and unnecessary complexity should be avoided. The phrase has been associated with aircraft engineer Kelly Johnson (1910–1990). The term "KISS principle" was in popular use by 1970. Variations on the phrase include "keep it short and simple" and "keep it simple and straightforward".

To best describe a layout when authoring a design document, you want something that is simple and easy to understand when describing a layout such as this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fczkUV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

"Two Column Layout" is simple, spot on descriptive and is very difficult to misinterpret. KISS at it's best!

Similarly, we have the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMvUlO.png)</sup>

"Three Column Layout" and "Border Layout" are spot on descriptive. Don't overcomplicate something that describes exactly what it refers to!

But what about "Two Panel Layout"? Well, I'm not sure what you mean there. What makes it different than a "Two Column Layout"? Draw a picture in your document, label it "Two Panel Layout" and describe the differences therein. Everyone now knows what it is.